# Git hooks with git notes?

Tags: git, githooks, git-notes

Is it possible to use any `git` hooks with `git notes`?

In other words, are any `git` hooks triggered by a `git notes add -m "Some note"`?

I have tried a few hooks (`update`, `post-commit`) but so far none seem to be triggered on a `git notes add`.

Comment: I think the answer is no. https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks mentions notes only for `post-rewrite` hook and only in the context of notes copying during commands that rewrite commits (`git commit --amend`, `git rebase`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: no [client-side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_client_side_hooks) is triggered by [`git notes add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-notes#Documentation/git-notes.txt-add)

And furthermore, that feature was not ever requested, it seems, [in the Git mailing list](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:public-inbox.org/git/%20%22git%20notes%22%20%22hook%22&client=firefox-b-d&ei=HMnLXJyOLKGNlwSr7r3oDQ&start=20&sa=N&ved=0ahUKEwicjOqryP7hAhWhxoUKHSt3D904ChDw0wMIbA&biw=1534&bih=750).